# ADO.NET Entity Framework: Update Wizard did not add new tables

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ado.net-entity-data-model

I had created new tables but when I click update model from database, the new tables werent added. I tried setting primary keys and all, but it couldnt work too. And when I click the update model from database, in the dialog box, the "add" column, I selected Table but none of the tables stated there. So when I click finish, none of the new tables is being added to the model. I dont know why my tables not shown in the add column. Anyone know what is wrong with it?

Comment: first of all - Please show your code here

Comment: my code is very long and it exceeds the words limit here.

Comment: Neee more info. Which version of EF? Visual Studio?  SQL Server?  Tables with PKs?  Connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet so I'll ask my question as an answer. Under the add tab, did you check the checkboxes for the table that you wanted to add? Secondly after you have added do you see your tables in the edmx file?

Comment: Nope, Cause no tables were being shown. In the dialog box, the "add" column, I selected Table but none of the tables stated there. So when I click finish, none of the new tables is being added to the model. Nope, no tables being shown in the edmx file too.

Comment: Make sure you are infact pointing to the database you are updating. Thats all I can think of now